# How to build a scalable counter within azure functions

Tags: azure, concurrency, counter, azure-functions

I'm wanting to build a scalable counter that I can increment within **Azure** functions code.  This solution seems like it would do the trick: 
http://blog.smarx.com/posts/architecting-scalable-counters-with-windows-azure 
However, the above was assuming a classic web server architecture. Any suggestions for how to construct the ID field when using azure functions?  Could use the function's invocation id (`ExecutionContext.InvocationId`) but that would add a counter row for every function call which would get out of hand pretty fast.

Answer (score 3):

Unless for purely academic reasons, I would not bother hand-crafting distributed counter in-memory.

Instead, I would use something like Redis and its [`INCR` command](https://redis.io/commands/incr). Of course, you can call it from your Azure Function. This will scale to huge number without much effort.

Answer (score 0):

InvocationId will be per function instance. 
Azure Functions still run in a process, so you could still get the machine name and process id using traditional means, something like:

```
var id = Environment.MachineName + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
```

The challenge is that with serverless, we specifically try to abstract away from the underlying infrastructure, so instances could potentially run on many different processes over time.